# Pseudo 3D effect based on sprites with touch control on iphone / ipad

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, 3d, sprite

I am looking for a way to reproduce this html/js effect in objective-C / cocoa-touch

http://spritespin.ginie.eu/

I have been thinking of using a webview but i'd like to have it in native code.

Any clue, lib or links ? Thank you in advance !

Comment: You have a list of images and you want to be able to pan a finger to move through the list?

Comment: Right. An image list or a spritesheet.

Comment: If nothing exist, i will probably write a small lib :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `UIImageView`. If you just provide it with the list if images it can animate through them for you. If you enable user interaction and add a pan gesture recognizer you can detect touches and explicitly choose and set the image based on the touch position.